# If $X$ and $Y$ are coprime to $Z$, then so is their product $XY$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given is $X$ is coprime to $Z$ and $Y$ is coprime to $Z$ prove $XY$ is coprime to $Z$.

I know you can use Bezout's lemma to say $1=aX+bZ$ and $1=cY+dZ$ but I don't know how to actually do the proof.

Any ideas?

Comment: The prime factorization of $XY$ is the same as that of $X$ times that of $Y$. It is clear that it won't share any factors with $Z$.

Comment: @AvZ that's true but sometimes the result is proved as a preparation to show uniqueness of prime factorization, so this might not be available.

Answer (score 2):

aX + bZ = 1 and cY + dZ = 1

=> (aX + bZ)(cY + dZ) = 1

=> (ac)XY + (adX + bcY + bdZ)Z = 1

Therefore etc.

Comment: So if you can write $1=ax+by$ then $a$ and $b$ are coprime? I.e it is an if and only if situation?

Comment: Yes it is; this is why it's very useful.

Comment: Ah I see okay thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $XY$ and $Z$ are not coprime, then there's a prime number dividing both $XY$ and $Z$...