# discrete math - one equation with two variables

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

look at this equation:

101x + 103y = 1

how can i prove if there is a solution or not to this equation?

**x and y must to be intergers**

i really have no any idea how is possible to prove something like this, hope you can give me any direction.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the [Bezout Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125321/does-bezouts-lemma-work-both-ways). Since $gcd(101,103)=1$, there is such an integer solution.

Comment: $51\times101-50\times103=1$

Comment: wow i didn't think about it, thanks...